# Summation notation for $1*3+2*4+3*5+...+40*42$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, notation, solution-verification

For this pattern $1*3+2*4+3*5+...+40*42$

my summation notation was: $\sum_{i=1}^n i(i+2), n = 40$

Which gives me the answer of $23780.$

Is this correct notation?

Comment: To check, expand the brackets inside the sum then write the sum as a sum of known sums.

Comment: @Shaun - Hi, I was actually just wondering if that's the correct summation notation for the given pattern. I'll edit to make that more clear, sorry about that.

Comment: The summation notation you write is correct.  "*Which gives me the answer of 23780.*"  If you were expected to find the result of the summation, that wasn't mentioned, but okay.  How did you get the result though?  If you were allowed to use a calculator, then say so, otherwise if you were expected to do this by hand you should share how you got that.

Comment: @JMoravitz - Hi, yeah I edited the post to make it more clear that I'm just wondering if the notation is correct, as I know how to solve it from there. Thanks.

Comment: As a nitpick., I wouldn't have bothered with naming the variable $n$... just write $40$ as the upper limit in the summation.  Even better for a faster time with working this out by hand, you could have instead done this $\sum\limits_{i=2}^{41}(i^2-1)$ noting that $(i+1)(i-1)=i^2-1$ and shifting the index slightly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The summation notation is right. The sum is also correct, since

$$\sum_{i=1}^ni(i+2)=\sum _{i=1}^n i^2+2i=\sum_{i=1}^ni^2+2\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+2\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$
After you set $n=40$, you get $23780$.

Answer (score 0):

Your notation appears to be correct, assuming that, as you did, the $i$th term of the sum is $i(i+2)$; to evaluate it, expand the brackets inside the sum then write the sum as a sum of known, standard sums.

Answer (score 0):

That is right.

To get an expression for
the sum with $n$ terms,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=1}^ni(i+2)
&=\sum_{i=1}^n(i^2+2i)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n((i+1)^2-1)\\
&=\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}(i^2-1)\\
&=\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}i^2-\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}1\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i^2-1-n\\
&=\dfrac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)}{6}-(n+1)\\
&=\dfrac{(n+1)((n+2)(2n+3)-6)}{6}\\
&=\dfrac{(n+1)(2n^2+7n)}{6}\\
&=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+7)}{6}\\
\end{array}
$

If $n=40$, this is

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+7)}{6}
&=\dfrac{40\ 41\ 87}{6}\\
&=20\ 41\ 29\\
&=20 (40+1)(30-1)\\
&=20 (1200-10-1)\\
&=20 (1189)\\
&= 23780\\
\end{array}
$